# Django Pagination based on Boolean value from view

Tags: python, django, pagination

I am new to Django and trying to set pagination based on different value in URL.

In views.py

```
class PageListView(ListView):
    model = FbPage
    paginate_by = 50

    all_pages = False

    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.request.session['all_pages'] = self.all_pages
        return super(PageListView, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
```

And in URL:

```
    url(r'^$', PageListView.as_view(), name='show_page_list'),
    url(r'^all/$', PageListView.as_view(all_pages=True), name='all_show_page_list'),
```

In template:

```
        <div class="pagination">

        <span class="page-links">
            {% if page_obj.has_previous %}

                    <a href="{% url 'show_page_list' %}?page={{ page_obj.previous_page_number }}">previous</a>
            {% endif %}
            <span class="page-current">
                Page {{ page_obj.number }} of {{ page_obj.paginator.num_pages }} (total {{ page_obj.paginator.count }} items).
            </span>
            {% if page_obj.has_next %}
                <a href="{% url 'show_page_list' %}?page={{ page_obj.next_page_number }}">next</a>
            {% endif %}
        </span>
    </div>
```

Problem is, even if I am in `home/all` page, it links back to `home` page pagination since I am passing `show_page_list` instead of `all_show_page_list`

How can I set an if else in template so that I can have correct pagination  or I should do something different?

Comment: You may want to give this a read over. It breaks down ListView rather well. https://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/1.9/django.views.generic.list/ListView/

Comment: Showing "all" is likely to make your page loads continually slower as you get more objects included in your database. I'd recommend going with the "amazon" approach of paginating by 5,10,25,50 or similar.

Comment: You can review my paginator. It's raw, but it work and it has a good logic. https://github.com/mrvol/uni_paginator

Comment: Thanks  EmettSpeer and mrvol for your kindness. I will definitely look into those. For now I am still at a learning phase so I would like to implement it myself to learn more. sayse I will look up on that. It is a good idea. Can I do that using built in paginator in Django?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define your pattern name in context variable and pass it into `{% url %}` tag:

```
<div>
   <div class="pagination">

    <span class="page-links">
        {% if page_obj.has_previous %}

                <a href="{% url list_url %}?page={{ page_obj.previous_page_number }}">previous</a>
        {% endif %}
        <span class="page-current">
            Page {{ page_obj.number }} of {{ page_obj.paginator.num_pages }} (total {{ page_obj.paginator.count }} items).
        </span>
        {% if page_obj.has_next %}
            <a href="{% url list_url %}?page={{ page_obj.next_page_number }}">next</a>
        {% endif %}
    </span>
</div>
```

And in your view:

```
class PageListView(ListView):
    model = FbPage
    paginate_by = 50

    all_pages = False

    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.request.session['all_pages'] = self.all_pages
        return super(PageListView, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(PageListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)

        context['list_url'] = 'all_show_page_list' if self.all_pages else 'show_page_list'

        return context
```

Comment: Thank you. It works perfectly. I do have a problem with `Reverse for 'list_url' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []` but it might have to do with my version of django and not your code because it works perfectly in my dev machine but not in deployment server

Comment: I really wonder why it works in `Django 1.7.1` with `python 2.7.6` but fails in `python 2.7.9`

Comment: putting variables into `{% url %}` tag as url name is available from django 1.5, if you're using 1.4 on your server (and you probably do), it won't work.

Comment: I found that I had to restart the server. Once I did that it started to work fine. Thank you again.